# How to add extra condition to the login to check for the value for a certain string field in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, google-cloud-firestore

My code below for conditional rendering is able to load specific screen based on specified email user from Firebase authentication. But i can't seem to make it work for specific value of a string field from Firestore Collection. e.g Age > 30. How do i make it work?

````
  const CheckUser({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final user = snapshot.data;
            if (user?.email == 'myemail@yahoo.com') {
              return const Home2Page();
            } else {
              return const HomePage();
            }
          } else {
            return const AuthPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

````
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final user = snapshot.data;
            if (user?.email == 'email@yahoo.com') {
              return const Home2Page();
            } else {
              return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('age', isEqualTo: 37).snapshots(),
                builder: (context, usersSnapshot) {
                  if (usersSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  
                  if (usersSnapshot.hasData && usersSnapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                    return const Home2Page();
                  } else {
                    return const HomePage();
                  }
                },
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const AuthPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );```
````